# How do you import an AtmosphereJS package?

Tags: angular, typescript, meteor, atmosphere.js

Following the [instructions found here](https://guide.meteor.com/using-atmosphere-packages.html#using-atmosphere) for using atmosphere packages in my meteor project I still get errors when I run `meteor` in my meteor project.

For example referencing `vsivsi:job-collection` like so

```
import { JobCollection } from 'meteor/vsivsi:job-collection'
```

results in the error

```
app.component.ts (14,31): Cannot find module 'meteor/vsivsi:job-collection'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the package installed?

Comment: yes, a `meteor list` returns version 1.5.1 is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [README](https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-job-collection#installation):

> The package exposes a global object `JobCollection` on both client and server.

In other words, the package doesn't need importing! You can just use `JobCollection` in your application once you've installed it. This corresponds with the line in the instructions you posted saying:

> Sometimes a package will have no exports and simply have side effects when included in your app. In such cases you don’t need to import the package at all after installing.

I don't know enough about the package to know whether there's a specific reason for it using globals, or if it's just being naughty and not using modules properly.

EDIT:

As mentioned in the comments, it seems that this library doesn't include TypeScript definitions. You could write your own (if you do, please submit them as a pull request to the library so we can all use them!), but as a stopgap measure, if you add this somewhere in your application, it'll prevent the errors from occurring.

```
declare var JobCollection: any;
```

I like to have a file called `definitions.d.ts` in all my TypeScript projects to stuff these little bits of definition code into.

Comment: So given that I still get errors. Following the packages documentation [here](https://atmospherejs.com/vsivsi/job-collection#quick-example) I get an error in my `server/jobs.ts` saying `server/jobs.ts (7,22): Cannot find name 'JobCollection'.`. Is this a problem with the package or should I just migrate this discussion to the github repo in an issue?

Comment: @gh0st: That sounds like an issue with missing TypeScript definitions (which there's an [unresolved issue](https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-job-collection/issues/212)). I'll update my answer.

Comment: @gh0st: Done! Hopefully that'll get you up and running.